# Переназначение переменных в javascript

Tags: javascript

Нужно заменить одну переменную, на другую, а вторую изменить. Типо такого:

```
a = b;
b = c;
```

Проблема в следующем. Нужно поменять значения переменных в массиве. Допустим `inventory[3]['color'] = 'black', inventory[4]['color'] = 'red'`.

```
inventory[3] = inventory[4];
inventory[4]['color'] = 'green';
```

Тогда в конце получаю `inventory[3]['color'] == 'green'`
Объясните еще почему мой способ не работает, пожалуйста

Comment: Если поменять местами, то попробуйте так: `[inventory[3], inventory[4]] = [inventory[4], inventory[3]];` Хотя, этот способ не подойдет, если, кроме `color` , есть другие свойства и их затрагивать не нужно

Comment: Спасибо большое, не подскажите теперь, почему мой способ не работает?

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
inventory[3] = inventory[4];
```

Надо

```
inventory[3]['color'] = inventory[4]['color'];
```

Comment: Так мне нужно целиком заменить inventory[4] на место inventory[3]